# How to implement a TraitId?

Tags: rust

The `std::any` module contains a `TypeId`. I would like to implement an equivalent `TraitId`, that is some mean of uniquely identifying a trait.

This implementation need not be "entirely automated", but it would be somewhat easier if I could rely on some automation and avoid attributing IDs myself.

My "best" idea so far was to create a marker type for myself, then implement all traits on it (with a healthy abuse of `panic!()`) and then use `std::raw::TraitObject` to get the v-ptr out of the trait representation and use *that* as my unique identifier.

```
struct Marker;

#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, Eq, PartialEq, Ord, PartialOrd)]
struct TraitId { id: *mut () }

fn trait_id<T: ?Sized>() -> TraitId
    where Marker: T
{
    let m = Marker { a: 1 };
    let t: &T = &m;
    let id: u64 = unsafe {
        let r: raw::TraitObject = mem::transmute(t);
        mem::transmute(r.vtable)
    };
    TraitId { id: id }
}
```

It seemed like a neat idea, right until ([link](http://is.gd/33AJaz)):

```
<anon>:14:19: 14:20 error: `T` is not a trait
<anon>:14     where Marker: T
                            ^
```

Does anyone know how to either constraint `T` so it is a trait OR fabricate a (unique per trait) `TraitId`?

Comment: TypeId uses intrinsics internally. Perhaps we should use `typeid(Box<Trait>)` to get TraitID?

Comment: @Manishearth: Clever! But I cannot manage to make it compile, unfortunately. (`Box<T + 'static>` => "expected reference to a trait")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abusing `TypeId` to get `TraitId` works.

```rust
#![feature(core)]
fn main() {
 println!("{:?}", trait_id::<Clone>());
 println!("{:?}", trait_id::<Sync>());
}

use std::marker::{Reflect};
use std::any::TypeId;

#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq, Debug)]
struct TraitId(TypeId);

fn trait_id<T: ?Sized + Reflect + 'static>() -> TraitId
{
    TraitId(TypeId::of::<T>())
}
```

[Playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%23!%5Bfeature(core)%5D%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20trait_id%3A%3A%3CClone%3E())%3B%0A%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20trait_id%3A%3A%3CSync%3E())%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ause%20std%3A%3Amarker%3A%3A%7BReflect%7D%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Aany%3A%3ATypeId%3B%0A%0A%23%5Bderive(Clone%2C%20Copy%2C%20PartialEq%2C%20Eq%2C%20Debug)%5D%0Astruct%20TraitId(TypeId)%3B%0A%0Afn%20trait_id%3CT%3A%20%3FSized%20%2B%20Reflect%20%2B%20%27static%3E()%20-%3E%20TraitId%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20TraitId(TypeId%3A%3Aof%3A%3A%3CT%3E())%0A%7D&version=nightly)

Comment: Nice; I was fiddling around with function pointers but this works nicely.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Actually, I don't think we even need the  `Box`; `TypeId::of::<T>` should just work

Comment: Actually... `unsafe { std::intrinsics::type_id::<Clone>() }` works out of the box. I feel a bit silly now for assuming that `TypeId` would not work...

Comment: @MatthieuM. yeah, that's basically what I'm saying :)